# Accessing Grapevine REST Server over network

Tags: c#, rest, grapevine

I want to implement REST interface for my application. After some search, I select Grapevine (Got from stackoverflow itself.). It works fine. the problem is, the server accessible using localhost only. Even the server listening on 0.0.0.0:8080, the server is not accessible over network. Also only hostname localhost is working. Please help me to solve the problem or suggest another .net REST server.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't reach the server from a remote machine, you are likely running a firewall that is blocking inbound traffic to the port you are listening on. Try opening the port on your firewall, and see if that works for you.

[How to Open a Port in the Windows 7 Firewall](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-open-a-port-in-the-windows-7-firewall.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use "+" as hostname and reserve the url by using the `netsh` utility:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user=everyone
```

For more Information [Notes On Using HttpListener](https://sukona.github.io/Grapevine/en/using-httplistener.html)